# Chrome Extension Server Requirements

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, server

I have a chrome extension I have made and it connects to its own database. I want to publish this extension but I don't have it connected to any server. I read a few things that made it seem like I don't need to make my own server instance in order to run and publish my extension meaning it will run on the chrome web store server. Is this true? Or do i just need to make my own server instance before publishing?

Comment: You don't need to own a server to make requests to it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how I would do that? My only experience is with AWS EC2 instances and it is very minimal experience.

Comment: Actually after this comment I'm no longer sure I understand the question. Maybe [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)?